# Why does "false && true" not exit with set -e in Bash?

Tags: bash, boolean

Why is the third case returning success with exit code 0?

```
case 1 ~$ bash -c 'set -e; false || true; echo success'; echo $?
success
0
case 2 ~$ bash -c 'set -e; true || false; echo success'; echo $?
success
0
case 3 ~$ bash -c 'set -e; false && true; echo success'; echo $?
success
0
case 4 ~$ bash -c 'set -e; true && false; echo success'; echo $?
1
case 5 ~$ bash -c 'set -e; false || false; echo success'; echo $?
1
case 6 ~$  bash -c 'set -e; false && false; echo success'; echo $?
success
0
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105): `set -e` is subtle and hard to reason about (and has even-more-subtle implementation differences between different shells and release versions), and a large proportion of the bash community is in agreement with the proposition that it should never be used.

Comment: Quoting the page " It has useful semantics, so to exclude it from the toolbox is to give into FUD."

Comment: @eckes: that's only a certain obscure user's opinion. GreyCat and geirha have another opinion.

Comment: @eckes, ...notably, GreyCat is the primary *author* of that FAQ, and the BashGuide, and primary person responsible for the Freenode #bash IRC channel. If there's going to be argument from authority, it's worth noting who the relevant authorities are.

Comment: Feel free to argument by authority - I think it is typically a bad idea to have shell scripts without `set -e`. It does enforce proper error handling. That alone is worth it.

Answer (score 4):

The [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) for `set -e` says:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is [...] part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, [...]

The command list in question is `false && true`. The failing command is `false`, which is not the last command in the list, so the shell does not exit. The `0` you're seeing is the exit status of `echo success`.

Answer (score 2):

`set -e` is a bit subtle.

From the [reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set):

> -e
>
> When this option is on, when any command fails (for any of the reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or by returning an exit
>   status greater than zero), the shell immediately shall exit, as if by
>   executing the exit special built-in utility with no arguments, with
>   the following exceptions:
>
> 1. The failure of any individual command in a multi-command pipeline shall not cause the shell to exit. Only the failure of the
>      pipeline itself shall be considered.
> 2. The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, a pipeline
>      beginning with the ! reserved word, **or any command of an AND-OR list
>      other than the last.**
> 3. If the exit status of a compound command other than a subshell command was the result of a failure while -e was being ignored, then
>      -e shall not apply to this command.
>
> This requirement applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately. For example, in:
>
> ```
> set -e; (false; echo one) | cat; echo two
> ```
>
> the false command causes the subshell to exit without executing echo one; however, echo two is executed because the exit status of the
>   pipeline (false; echo one) | cat is zero.

Since `false && true` is part of an *AND or OR list and `false` isn't the last,* the shell doesn't exit immediately.

So `echo success` is executed, and it's return code is `0`.

By the way, have you noticed case 6?

Comment: By that logic, case 4 should write "success" as well, since `true && false` is an AND list. The exception mentioned in melpomene's answer is very relevant here.

Comment: @Heinzi: yeah, I should have linked the [latest version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set), they augmented this part, actually... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

`true && false; echo success` returns the return code from `echo` which is 0.

```
 bash -c 'false && true'; echo $?
```

yields `1` as expected. Pheew!

Aside: `bash -c 'set -e; false || false; echo success'; echo $?` yields return code `1` because second command does not execute `echo` (stops at `false` because errors stop the current command), note that `success` is not printed.